# How to add gridview row counter in a custom gridview row?

Tags: android

I have a gridview filled from a sqlite database list of objects and I need to set the custom gridview row textview named by **@+id/row** by the row count even if the gridview has multiple cells per row 
the row layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the gridview

```
<com.linkatapps.salaty.demo.HeaderGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="3"
    tools:context="com.linkatapps.salaty.demo.GridViewActivity">


</com.linkatapps.salaty.demo.HeaderGridView>
```

from the header gridview class

```
public class HeaderGridView extends GridView {
    private static final String TAG = "HeaderGridView";

    /**
     * A class that represents a fixed view in a list, for example a header at the top
     * or a footer at the bottom.
     */
    private static class FixedViewInfo {
        /**
         * The view to add to the grid
         */
        public View view;
        public ViewGroup viewContainer;
        /**
         * The data backing the view. This is returned from {@link ListAdapter#getItem(int)}.
         */
        public Object data;
        /**
         * <code>true</code> if the fixed view should be selectable in the grid
         */
        public boolean isSelectable;
    }

    private ArrayList<FixedViewInfo> mHeaderViewInfos = new ArrayList<FixedViewInfo>();

    private void initHeaderGridView() {
        super.setClipChildren(false);
    }

    public HeaderGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initHeaderGridView();
    }

    public HeaderGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initHeaderGridView();
    }

    public HeaderGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initHeaderGridView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter instanceof HeaderViewGridAdapter) {
            ((HeaderViewGridAdapter) adapter).setNumColumns(getNumColumns());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setClipChildren(boolean clipChildren) {
        // Ignore, since the header rows depend on not being clipped
    }

    /**
     * Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the grid. If addHeaderView is
     * called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
     * added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
     * <p>
     * NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so HeaderGridView can wrap
     * the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header views.
     *
     * @param v            The view to add.
     * @param data         Data to associate with this view
     * @param isSelectable whether the item is selectable
     */
    public void addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && !(adapter instanceof HeaderViewGridAdapter)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot add header view to grid -- setAdapter has already been called.");
        }
        FixedViewInfo info = new FixedViewInfo();
        FrameLayout fl = new FullWidthFixedViewLayout(getContext());
        fl.addView(v);
        info.view = v;
        info.viewContainer = fl;
        info.data = data;
        info.isSelectable = isSelectable;
        mHeaderViewInfos.add(info);
        // in the case of re-adding a header view, or adding one later on,
        // we need to notify the observer
        if (adapter != null) {
            ((HeaderViewGridAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the grid. If addHeaderView is
     * called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
     * added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
     * <p>
     * NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so HeaderGridView can wrap
     * the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header views.
     *
     * @param v The view to add.
     */
    public void addHeaderView(View v) {
        addHeaderView(v, null, true);
    }

    public int getHeaderViewCount() {
        return mHeaderViewInfos.size();
    }

    /**
     * Removes a previously-added header view.
     *
     * @param v The view to remove
     * @return true if the view was removed, false if the view was not a header
     * view
     */
    public boolean removeHeaderView(View v) {
        if (mHeaderViewInfos.size() > 0) {
            boolean result = false;
            ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            if (adapter != null && ((HeaderViewGridAdapter) adapter).removeHeader(v)) {
                result = true;
            }
            removeFixedViewInfo(v, mHeaderViewInfos);
            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void removeFixedViewInfo(View v, ArrayList<FixedViewInfo> where) {
        int len = where.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            FixedViewInfo info = where.get(i);
            if (info.view == v) {
                where.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if (mHeaderViewInfos.size() > 0) {
            HeaderViewGridAdapter hadapter = new HeaderViewGridAdapter(mHeaderViewInfos, adapter);
            int numColumns = getNumColumns();
            if (numColumns > 1) {
                hadapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
            }
            super.setAdapter(hadapter);
        } else {
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private class FullWidthFixedViewLayout extends FrameLayout {
        public FullWidthFixedViewLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int targetWidth = HeaderGridView.this.getMeasuredWidth()
                    - HeaderGridView.this.getPaddingLeft()
                    - HeaderGridView.this.getPaddingRight();
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(targetWidth,
                    MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec));
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    /**
     * ListAdapter used when a HeaderGridView has header views. This ListAdapter
     * wraps another one and also keeps track of the header views and their
     * associated data objects.
     * <p>This is intended as a base class; you will probably not need to
     * use this class directly in your own code.
     */
    private static class HeaderViewGridAdapter implements WrapperListAdapter, Filterable {
        // This is used to notify the container of updates relating to number of columns
        // or headers changing, which changes the number of placeholders needed
        private final DataSetObservable mDataSetObservable = new DataSetObservable();
        private final ListAdapter mAdapter;
        private int mNumColumns = 1;
        // This ArrayList is assumed to NOT be null.
        ArrayList<FixedViewInfo> mHeaderViewInfos;
        boolean mAreAllFixedViewsSelectable;
        private final boolean mIsFilterable;

        public HeaderViewGridAdapter(ArrayList<FixedViewInfo> headerViewInfos, ListAdapter adapter) {
            mAdapter = adapter;
            mIsFilterable = adapter instanceof Filterable;
            if (headerViewInfos == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("headerViewInfos cannot be null");
            }
            mHeaderViewInfos = headerViewInfos;
            mAreAllFixedViewsSelectable = areAllListInfosSelectable(mHeaderViewInfos);
        }

        public int getHeadersCount() {
            return mHeaderViewInfos.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return (mAdapter == null || mAdapter.isEmpty()) && getHeadersCount() == 0;
        }

        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            if (numColumns < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of columns must be 1 or more");
            }
            if (mNumColumns != numColumns) {
                mNumColumns = numColumns;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        private boolean areAllListInfosSelectable(ArrayList<FixedViewInfo> infos) {
            if (infos != null) {
                for (FixedViewInfo info : infos) {
                    if (!info.isSelectable) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public boolean removeHeader(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mHeaderViewInfos.size(); i++) {
                FixedViewInfo info = mHeaderViewInfos.get(i);
                if (info.view == v) {
                    mHeaderViewInfos.remove(i);
                    mAreAllFixedViewsSelectable = areAllListInfosSelectable(mHeaderViewInfos);
                    mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                return getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns + mAdapter.getCount();
            } else {
                return getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                return mAreAllFixedViewsSelectable && mAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            // Header (negative positions will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
            int numHeadersAndPlaceholders = getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            if (position < numHeadersAndPlaceholders) {
                return (position % mNumColumns == 0)
                        && mHeaderViewInfos.get(position / mNumColumns).isSelectable;
            }
            // Adapter
            final int adjPosition = position - numHeadersAndPlaceholders;
            int adapterCount = 0;
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
                if (adjPosition < adapterCount) {
                    return mAdapter.isEnabled(adjPosition);
                }
            }
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // Header (negative positions will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
            int numHeadersAndPlaceholders = getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            if (position < numHeadersAndPlaceholders) {
                if (position % mNumColumns == 0) {
                    return mHeaderViewInfos.get(position / mNumColumns).data;
                }
                return null;
            }
            // Adapter
            final int adjPosition = position - numHeadersAndPlaceholders;
            int adapterCount = 0;
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
                if (adjPosition < adapterCount) {
                    return mAdapter.getItem(adjPosition);
                }
            }
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            int numHeadersAndPlaceholders = getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            if (mAdapter != null && position >= numHeadersAndPlaceholders) {
                int adjPosition = position - numHeadersAndPlaceholders;
                int adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
                if (adjPosition < adapterCount) {
                    return mAdapter.getItemId(adjPosition);
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                return mAdapter.hasStableIds();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Header (negative positions will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
            int numHeadersAndPlaceholders = getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            if (position < numHeadersAndPlaceholders) {
                View headerViewContainer = mHeaderViewInfos
                        .get(position / mNumColumns).viewContainer;
                if (position % mNumColumns == 0) {
                    return headerViewContainer;
                } else {
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = new View(parent.getContext());
                    }
                    // We need to do this because GridView uses the height of the last item
                    // in a row to determine the height for the entire row.
                    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    convertView.setMinimumHeight(headerViewContainer.getHeight());
                    return convertView;
                }
            }
            // Adapter
            final int adjPosition = position - numHeadersAndPlaceholders;
            int adapterCount = 0;
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
                if (adjPosition < adapterCount) {
                    return mAdapter.getView(adjPosition, convertView, parent);
                }
            }
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            int numHeadersAndPlaceholders = getHeadersCount() * mNumColumns;
            if (position < numHeadersAndPlaceholders && (position % mNumColumns != 0)) {
                // Placeholders get the last view type number
                return mAdapter != null ? mAdapter.getViewTypeCount() : 1;
            }
            if (mAdapter != null && position >= numHeadersAndPlaceholders) {
                int adjPosition = position - numHeadersAndPlaceholders;
                int adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
                if (adjPosition < adapterCount) {
                    return mAdapter.getItemViewType(adjPosition);
                }
            }
            return AdapterView.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER_OR_FOOTER;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                return mAdapter.getViewTypeCount() + 1;
            }
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (mIsFilterable) {
                return ((Filterable) mAdapter).getFilter();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ListAdapter getWrappedAdapter() {
            return mAdapter;
        }

        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

with GridView Adapter

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<City> cities;

    static int count = 1;

    // 1
    public GridviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<City> cities) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    // 2
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cities.size();
    }

    // 3
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // 4
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    // 5
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final City city = cities.get(position);

        // 2
        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "City:" + city.getCity() + " - " + "Country:" + city.getCountry(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // 3
        final TextView cityTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        final TextView countryTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country);

        // 4
        cityTV.setText(city.getCity());
        countryTV.setText(city.getCountry());
        int poss = position;
        if (position == 0) {
            final TextView counter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row);
            counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;
        } else if (position % 3 == 0 && position < cities.size()) {
            final TextView counter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row);
            counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;
        } else if (position > cities.size()) {
            count = 1;
        }

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

setting gridview adapter

```
   final HeaderGridView gridView = (HeaderGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_header, null);
        gridView.addHeaderView(v);
        GridviewAdapter booksAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, cities);
        gridView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
```